# VBA: Trying to click a button in IE but guessing may not be actual buttons?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, excel, vba

Im on an intranet aspx site that has daily reports, I can navigate to the webpage, log in with username and password, but then on the first page there is a row of buttons, and i want to click on one of them to open a section of the reports. I'm guessing im using the wrong commands to click on it. This is the part of my code that isn't doing anything. Where ie is my Internet Explorer application.

```
Dim btnInput As Object
Dim ElementCol As Object
Set ElementCol = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each btnInput In ElementCol
    If btnInput.Value = "x:WebTab1.4:mkr:ti3" Then
    btnInput.Click
Exit For
End If

Next btnInput
```

And this is what the html looks like.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ToolkitScriptManager1', 'fPFT', ['tUpdatePanel1','','tWebTab1$tmpl4$up4',''], [], [], 90, '');
//]]>
</script>

<div id="UpdatePanel1">
<div class="ig_HarvestControl igtab_HarvestTHControl :=CtlMain:layout" id="WebTab1"style="background-color:SaddleBrown;font-size:XX-Large;height:450px;width:764px;visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;">
<span class="igtab_HarvestTHHolder" id="x:WebTab1.0:mkr:head"><input type="hidden" id="WebTab1_clientState" name="WebTab1_clientState" /><input id="WebTab1.i" name="WebTab1.i" value="0" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;width:0px;height:0px;font-size:1px;padding:0px;left:20px;top:50%;border:0px;" />
<span class="igtab_HarvestTHHolderNoScroll"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHTab igtab_HarvestTHTabSel" id="x:WebTab1.1:mkr:ti0"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHTail igtab_HarvestTHTailSel"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHCenter igtab_HarvestTHCenterSel"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHText igtab_HarvestTHTextSel">Notes</span></span></span></span>
<span class="igtab_HarvestTHTab" id="x:WebTab1.2:mkr:ti1"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHTail"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHCenter"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHText">PFT Compare</span></span></span></span>
<span class="igtab_HarvestTHTab" id="x:WebTab1.3:mkr:ti2"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHTail"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHCenter"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHText">DPS</span></span></span></span>
<span class="igtab_HarvestTHTab" id="x:WebTab1.4:mkr:ti3"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHTail"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHCenter"><span class="igtab_HarvestTHText">PAS Toolbox</span></span></span></span>
```

The Buttons are Notes, PFT Compare, DPS, and PAS Toolbox. Is there another way im supposed to be trying to click them? I need PAS Toolbox. Anyones guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this ...Put `btnInput.FireEvent("onclick")`  this after `btnInput.Click`

Comment: @Santosh Didn't make any difference in the outcome. I must be referencing something wrong, there is no error, there just isn't a button click either...Is there some special way to code the click if it's within a form?

Comment: try Set ElementCol = ie.Document.getelementsbyid(“x:WebTab1.4:mkr:ti3”).click

Comment: @SathishK Runtime error 91 object variable not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried coding in the action of the button as opposed to trying to make your code "click" the button? In other words, just having your code open the desired section of the report and bypassing that button completely?

Comment: Thank you I figured it out, got to where I needed without clicking any buttons.